# regex duplicate matching? nested groups?

Tags: python, regex

This example is from a book.
The email regex looks like this:

```
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
        [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+               #username
        @                               #@ symbol
        [a-zA-Z-0-9.-]+                 #domain name
        (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})               #dot-something
        )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

match one or more occurrences of `[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]`, followed by an `@`, followed by one or more occurrences of `[a-zA-Z-0-9.-]`, followed by a dot, and 2 to 5 characters in `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
>>> emailRegex.findall('my email: stackoverflow@flow.com Please reach me here.')
[('stackoverflow@flow.com', '.com')]
```

How is `'.com'` included? the `.com` has already been matched with `[a-zA-Z-0-9.-]+`, then matched with `(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})` again? How does this work? I assume this has something to do with the fact that `emailRegex` has nested groups but I'm not familiar with how that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra set of parentheses in the pattern around the "dot something".  Every set of bare parentheses becomes a "match group" that gets returned in addition to the base pattern.  You can omit those extra parens if you don't want the group.

Comment: Im aware of that, but what im confused about is what happened between `#domain name` and `#dot-something`. `'.com'` already got matched, so how is this additional `'.com'` getting matched again?

Comment: Backtracking.  If the "#domain name" part matched `flow.com`, there'd be nothing for the "#dot-something" part, so the match would fail.  Thus, it backs up and retries until the domain gets split into two parts.

Comment: Not exactly. There is only one match, but because it has two groups those are presented separately. As described in the [`findall()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall): *"If one or more groups are present in the pattern, __return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples__ if the pattern has more than one group."* @lizardowl5151 And can be easily seen in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GoQ5jC/1). Remove the extra `()` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

`(email(.com))` the left most `(` in the regex is group(1), next left most `(` group(2) and so on. `(string(also string))`. `'string also string'` is group(1). `also string` is group(2).